# MinGW: libpng won't build properly

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, zlib, libpng

So I need this `libpng` to be statically link with my dll to be used by my exe. This dll is already done before until I switch my compiler from MSVC to MinGW, then this dll won't work anymore so I think I should rebuild it **again** through MinGW. Now, I cannot resolve the linker errors that I get into `libpng` so I decided to rebuild it(libpng) myself **again**. Another problem arises with this `zlib` or `libz` (I don't know their difference), so I rebuilt it **again** and produces `libz.a` using `make`. I then return to my dll where I want to link this `libpng`. No more linker errors. Now, when trying to run the test program it says, `"zlib-sgd-x86.dll is missing"`.. **dang!** there's no existing dll like this in the internet! Or I'm just too blind to find it. I use codeblocks as my IDE and.. I do think I mess up the settings there because it keeps adding the flags it added before repeatedly. So, I try to use `msys` to build **again** this dll file. Now it runs w/o any dll missing, but it seems not working. As I remember, I never change the code before in my dll and I'm pretty sure it has no bugs in there.

That dll I am talking about is a textureloader and w/ functions returning the texture id of image been loaded. And it returns an id of **4** for its very first texture loaded and no image is shown in the screen. I try all the things I knew on how to build those individual files I needed but still no luck on working it properly. I don't think the problem is in my dll.

Comment: you need to rebuild zlib from source. At the end you need a new libz.a and libz.dll.a ponting to zlib1.dll .

Comment: @moskito-x I didn't get it. I already builded zlib as well as libpng myself but still did not remove the problem. I am really stuck in this situation

Comment: okay, I'll give it a try.