# GNU gcc mysys make command no rule to make target libpng

Tags: c++, c, makefile, libpng

I've searched around for the problem I encounter when I try to compile libpng, but I can't find a solution.
When I run:

```
C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\libpng-1.6.21\scripts>make makefile.gcc libpng.a
```

I receive the following messages:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `makefile.gcc'.
make: *** No rule to make target `libpng.a'.  Stop.
```

I haven't modified the original makefile.gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you didn't call ./configure script.
Accoording to [this wiki](http://wiki.openttd.org/Compiling_on_Windows_using_MinGW) you need to run in msys shell:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng15/older-releases/1.5.16/libpng-1.5.16.tar.xz/download
tar xvfJ libpng-1.5.16.tar.xz
cd libpng-1.5.16
mv INSTALL INSTALL.txt
./configure
make install
```

Comment: After running ./configure , it says error:zlib was not installed, altough I copied zlib.h and zconf.h to the libpng directory.

Comment: @AlexV Now this question is duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610362/mingw-libpng-wont-build-properly. In the link to the wiki I've posted, is shown how to compile and install those dependencies too. If after reading this you still have question, go ahead. I personally did what you want to do 5 years ago.

Comment: I transformed zlib1.dll (got it precompiled) using the cp command into libzdll.a and placed it both in the libpng folder and in C:\MinGW\lib, but after running ./configure it still says it does not exist.

Comment: @AlexV You can't do this. You must compile and install zlib by make install first. The wiki I gave you shows how to.

Comment: I followed the steps presented in the wiki when compiling zlib, but i get this error: Cannot export gzopen_w: symbol not defined
Creating library file: libz.dll.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [zlib1.dll] Error 1